# Do anyone know how to sort stack using array.sort()? I just want to print the ordered list of points by their x coordinates. Any idea?

Tags: java, sorting

```
import java.util.*;

public class Point2D
{
  private double x;
  private double y;

  public Point2D(double x, double y)
  {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  private double Euclidean()
  {
    double Distance = Math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y));
    return Distance;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
    return "x: " + x + ", y: " + y;
  }

  public static class YOrder implements Comparator<Point2D>
  {    
    public int compare(Point2D self, Point2D other)
    {
      if (self.y > other.y)
        return 1;

      if (self.y < other.y)
        return -1;

      else
        return 0;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Stack<Point2D> stack = new Stack<Point2D>();

    while (!StdIn.isEmpty())
    {
      double x = StdIn.readDouble();
      double y = StdIn.readDouble();
      stack.push(new Point2D(x,y));
    }

    Arrays.sort(stack);
  }
}
```

This is for a class and I'm not allowed to use `Collections` or `ArrayList`.

Comment: You can simulate the stack in a Vector<Point2D>

Comment: I've added your comment to the question -- it's important to tell us about any constraints you're under so we don't waste our time with answers you can't use.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you need to supply a comparator.

```
Arrays.sort(stack.toArray(new Point2D[0](), new Comparator(){
    public int compare(Point2D a, Point2D b)
        { return a.x-b.x; }
});
```

Comment: I already have a comparator, and that's YOrder, I don't know why the array.sort() method is not using that

Comment: You want x order (you said), so you don't want to use the y order comparator.

Comment: Ah, I see.  If you want it to sort by default on Y, then Point2D has to implement Comparable.  Otherwise, you need to supply the Comparator as an argument, as in the solutions shown below.  Java doesn't know that you always want to use YOrder - you might have implemented an XOrder too.

Comment: I got this error message when try to compile with Collections.sort(stack, new YOrder());                            cannot find symbol symbol  : method sort(Stack<Point2D>,Point2D.YOrder)

Comment: If you look at both of the examples, you'll see that they each create an instance of the comparator.  In other words, you want Collections.sort(stack, **new YOrder()**);

Answer (score 1):

```
Arrays.sort(stack);
```

should be

```
 Collections.sort(stack, new YOrder());//pass comparator
```

Comment: due to the limitation by my teacher, I am not allowed to use collections or arraylist

Comment: @help: `java.util.Stack` is a **collection** of `java.util.List`.

Comment: @help: use arrays of `Point2D` and pass it to Arrays.sort(point2dArray,new YOrder());

Comment: Yes, better than my solution, if it's allowed to mangle the stack.  Note that I fixed mine to use toArray.

Comment: @help: `Arrays.sort(point2dArray,new YOrder());` : here new YOrder() instance is the comparator.

Comment: @help: you are not allowed to use Stack since it is a collection. Use array of type Pointer2D and pass the instance in the place of point2dArray. Since it is a homework. i just can guide you.